# Inserting XML in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xpath, sqlxml

I have an XML that looks like this:

```
   <Weather Location="Tuzla, Bosnia and Herzegovina">
  <Forecast>
     <Description>sky is clear</Description>
     <IconID>01d</IconID>
     <Date>2013-09-14</Date>
     <MinTemp>11</MinTemp>
     <MaxTemp>21</MaxTemp>
     <Pressure>994</Pressure>
     <Humidity>39</Humidity>
     <Wind>2</Wind>
   </Forecast>
   <Forecast>
     <Description>scattered clouds</Description>
     <IconID>03d</IconID>
     <Date>2013-09-15</Date>
     <MinTemp>9</MinTemp>
     <MaxTemp>24</MaxTemp>
     <Pressure>991</Pressure>
     <Humidity>44</Humidity>
     <Wind>1</Wind>
  </Forecast>
  <Forecast>
 ... //it has 10 Forecast parts   
</Weather>
```

In my database I have table that has just two fields, ID and this XML. So, when I insert new XML, i have to find out if there already exists XML with this location, and where date from first Forecast parts are same. 
Is there any way I can read only Date from first Forecast child of this root element Weather?
I know I have to go through my table and search every XML file I have, and that's not problem, but what I need is just date from only first forecast child.

Please help...

Comment: Lots of questions before you can get some help with it, but I'll start with two of the basic ones: 1), which RDBMS?  (MySQL, SQL Server, Postgre?), and 2) What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server. I'm trying something right now so that's why I haven't posted code yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can read Date from first Forecast and Location like (assuming this is SQL Server)

```
select
    t.Data.value('(Weather/@Location)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as Location,
    t.Data.value('(Weather/Forecast/Date)[1]', 'date') as Date
from table1 as t
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4b87b/3)</kbd>**